# Which is better? Passing object references, or passing properties themselves?

Tags: php, object

```
class Parent
{
    public function getSomething()
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function createChild($name)
    {
        return new Child ($name, $this);
    }
}

class Child
{
    public function __constructor ($name, Parent $parent)
    {
        $parent->getSomething();
    }
}
```

in this codes, a `Parent` creates a `Child` - and the `Child` wants something from its `Parent`, so a kind of cyclic references are there.
EDIT: so Parent creates Child(ren) but Children depends on the Parent, they cant be a standallone entity, thats how I feel.
If I rewrite this like this, will that be better?

```
class Parent
{
    private function getSomething()
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function createChild($name)
    {
        return new Child ($name, $this->getSomething);
    }
}

class Child
{
    public function __constructor ($name, $something)
    {
    }
}
```

but in this case, what if a `Child` needs more than that? Passing all those things to it via the constructor?

Comment: Why not have your Child extending your Parent class? Like in http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I updated the question: so Parent creates Child(ren) but Children depends on the Parent, they cant be a standallone entity, thats how I feel.

Comment: If children depend on the parent, but can't be stand alone you either extend the parent or make the child class abstract and implement it based on whatever you need from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Passing all those things to it via the constructor?

If `Child` only needs certain data that is present at instantiation time and *not call any methods* of `Parent`, I would say, yes.

**Reason:** It minimizes coupling. You don't introduce an unnecessary dependency.

---

<del>However, since you mentioned "references", you might want `Child` to get access to properties of `Parent` later. Then the cleaner approach is to do that through accessor methods of `Parent` instead of exposing those properties through the backdoor with references.</del>

<sup>I see, "references" was referring to the object reference. Made the wrong assumption here.</sup>

Comment: I updated the question: so Parent creates Child(ren) but Children depends on the Parent, they cant be a standallone entity, thats how I feel.

Comment: Just because `Parent` is the only user of `Child`, there is no need to make it an explicit dependency. If you look at the Composite pattern, there is no dependency from the leafs to the composites neither